# Are questions about facial hairstyles on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I would like to ask a question about sporting a certain type of imperial beard in a specific country while there on a short visit.  I would like to know if it draws some ire/snark or if nobody cares.

Is such a question on-topic?

**Edit**

Looks like its Hot! Gimme a badge folks!

[image]

Comment: Questions about dress code in countries and buildings within countries (like places of religion) seem to be on-topic so I cannot see why the presence or absence of beards would be off-topic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So, I randomly picked up a few similar questions:

- [Clothes in Egypt](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9166/what-to-wear-in-egypt-to-blend-in)
- [Tattoos in Japan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92389/should-i-just-cover-my-forearm-tattoo-in-japan)
- [Long beards while crossing borders](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21155/can-growing-a-beard-cause-problems-in-crossing-borders)
- [Long hair in Moscow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/114042/im-a-man-with-long-hair-am-i-likely-to-encounter-harassment-or-other-problems)
- [Big boobs in a Japanese onsen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44990/are-there-public-bath-etiquette-to-be-aware-of-in-japan-for-foreign-women)

Seeing these *on-topic* samples, I am sure your question is 110% on topic.

Comment: Ha nice titles!

Comment: Why the down-vote? What's in here to disagree with

Comment: @HankyPanky maybe someone didn't like the second word in the last link text. :(

Comment: Should have started that word with a big B, i agree. -1 :haha

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I kinda forgot you still exist, having a downvote from you over a weird reason is not something unexpected as far as I remember. Glad you sill around and as weird as you always been.

Comment: The “:(“ should have made it clear I didn’t approve of you being downvoted for that reason. To prove that I didn’t downvote you, I’m going to upvote you now. The vote total will go from 6 to 7, not from 6 to 8.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm come on man, do not change on me :( I kinda like you the way you :D

Answer (score 4):

I don't see why this wouldn't be on topic, as long as it is specific to travel.  You're posing the question in light of someone not familiar with the customs and practices of a country, so I think it would be fine.

It's not too far removed from what clothes to wear, which I would also consider to be acceptable (e.g. what to wear if you visit a mosque, or visit a conservative country in general).

Comment: Thanks! I will be asking this question tomorrow, let's see how it goes